# Ordenar tarjetas de la persona que tenga más dinero PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

estoy intentando crear un sistema, en el cual ordene cual es la persona que tenga más dinero, en este caso, quiero que ordene que el que esté en el primer puesto esté en el medio, el que este en el segundo en la derecha, y el que esté en el ultimo puesto en la izquierda. Pero con el código que intenté utilizar es que lo ordene de mayor a menor. ¿Hay alguna manera de solucionar esto?

Código:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$sqlget = "SELECT * FROM `characters` ORDER BY `characters`.`dinero` DESC LIMIT 3";
$sqldata = $dbh->query($sqlget) or die('error users');

while($row = $sqldata->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($row["CKuIDStaff"] == 1) {
        echo '<div class="profile-card">
        <b style="color: red;">Personaje Muerto</b>
        <br>
  <img src="skins/'.$row["skin"].'.png" alt="image1" class="profile-icon" />
  <div class="profile-name">'.$row["characterName"].'</div>
  <div class="profile-position">'.$row["yo"].'</div>
  <a href="personajes/'.$row["characterName"].'" class="button">Ver perfil</a>
</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="profile-card">
        <img src="skins/'.$row["skin"].'.png" alt="image1" class="profile-icon" />
        <div class="profile-name">'.$row["characterName"].'</div>
        <div class="profile-position">'.$row["yo"].'</div>
        <a href="personajes/'.$row["characterName"].'" class="button">Ver perfil</a>
      </div>';
    }
  
}
```

Comment: Dentro del while tan solo asigna las filas a una variable de array, por ejemplo, `$personajes[] = $row;` y luego, ya fuera del bucle, montate una vista HTML con la disposición que quieras y llama a los valores de esa variable por indice, donde 0 será el primero, 1 el segundo y 2 el tercero, por ejemplo, `$personajes[0]['skin']` para el skin del primero, `$personajes[1]['skin']` para el skin del segundo, etc.

Comment: @masterguru muy bien, eso si que funcionó, gracias